# fullCalendar events from ajax response not loading

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

Another question about ajax and fullCalendar.  I've read and tried previously suggested fixes here but all to no avail.  I cannot load JSON events to fullCalendar.  What am I doing wrong?

The $.ajax call is working and returning values.  The JSON has a parent element and the calendar array data is actually in jsondata.message.  The JSON.stringify in the code below is part of my various experiments.

I originally tried to use the fullCalendar eventSource with the built-in ajax retrieval.  I segregated the code thinking I was having call/communication issue.

I've tried [jsondata.message] and just jsondata.message.  I've tried parsing the JSON data into a standard array and passing the array to the events item.  Nothing I do short of copying the response and pasting it into the events: element within double-quotes works.

1. ajax call works and returns data.
2. since I can copy/paste the data from the ajax response into the code and the events load, its not the format of the data.

Could there be a limit to loading events?  There are approximately 4800 events I'm trying to load.

**AJAX call:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/appointment/ajax_get_available_records",
    type: "POST",
    data:{
        startdate: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:01"),
        enddate: end.format("YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59"),
        userid:<?= $doctor->user_id?>
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#errormsg').html("<p class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error while fetching calendar events!</p>'");
    },
    success: function(jsondata, status, xhr){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: [JSON.stringify(jsondata.message)],
                color: 'green',
                textColor: 'white' 
            });             
    },
    dataType: "json" 
});
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900
Content-Length:104282
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 04 Apr 2017 02:40:50 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

** Partial AJAX Response**

```
{"status":true,
"message":[{
            "doctor_user_id":"636",
            "title":"available",
            "start":"2017-04-03T19:10:00",
            "end":"2017-04-03T19:19:59",
            "clinic_id":"10",
            "clinic_location_id":"0"
           },
           {
            "doctor_user_id":"636",
            "title":"available",
            "start":"2017-04-03T19:20:00",
            "end":"2017-04-03T19:29:59",
            "clinic_id":"10",
            "clinic_location_id":"0"
           },
---- omitted  ----
```

**Server php 7.0/MySQL
Model:**

```
    function get_available_dates_in_range($user_id, $start_datetime = null , $end_datetime = null)
    {
        $startrange = date('Y-m-01 H:i:s',strtotime($start_datetime));
        $endrange = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($end_datetime));
    if($endrange == NULL) {
        $end_datetime = date_add($startrange,date_interval_create_from_date_string("INTERVAL 2 MONTHS")); 
        $endrange = date("Y-m-01 00:00:00",$end_datetime);
    }

    $this->db->select(
        "doctor_user_id, 
        status as `title`, 
        DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') as `start`, 
        DATE_FORMAT(date_add(datetime, Interval 599 SECOND),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') as end, 
        clinic_id, 
        clinic_location_id ");
    $this->db->where('doctor_user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('datetime >=', mysql_user_to_gmt_date($start_datetime));
    $this->db->where('datetime <=', mysql_user_to_gmt_date($end_datetime));
    $this->db->where('status', 'available');
    $this->db->order_by('datetime ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('schedule_records');
    return $query;  
}
```

**Codeigniter 3.1.4 controller:**

....

```
$query = $this->appointment_model->get_available_dates_in_range($userid, $startdate, $enddate);
$this->json_response($query->result_array());
```

**Encode and return JSON function**

```
function json_response($message = null, $code = 200) {
    // clear the old headers
    header_remove();
    // set the actual code
    http_response_code($code);
    // set the header to make sure cache is forced
    header("Cache-Control: no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900");
    // treat this as json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        200 => '200 OK',
        400 => '400 Bad Request',
        422 => 'Unprocessable Entity',
        500 => '500 Internal Server Error'
        );
    // ok, validation error, or failure
    header('Status: '.$status[$code]);
    // return the encoded json
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => $code < 300, // success or not?
        'message' => $message
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
events: [JSON.stringify(jsondata.message)]
```

looks dodgy to me. You're just making an array of one element with a giant string in it (because `JSON.stringify` does what it says, and makes your object into a string, and no longer a usable object. It's meant for displaying your JSON on-screen, not for processing). Try

```
events: jsondata.message
```

instead.

Although, really this whole code is the wrong way round - doing it like this you will have to handle the updating of data when the fullCalendar view changes (i.e. user presses next/prev) yourself. If you use fullCalendar's "events-as-a-function" you can use your own ajax code, but let fullCalendar handle querying the server again when new events need to be fetched.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function for more details and examples, but this is how I'd do it:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/appointment/ajax_get_available_records",
      type: "POST",
      data:{
        startdate: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:01"),
        enddate: end.format("YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59"),
        userid:<?= $doctor->user_id?>
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#errormsg').html("<p class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error while fetching calendar events!</p>'");
        console.log("Error fetching events: " + textStatus + errorThrown); //log the error for debugging
        callback([]); //no data was retrieved, so send an empty array of events to fullCalendar
      },
      success: function(jsondata, status, xhr){
        callback(jsondata.message); //sends the events to fullCalendar
      },
      dataType: "json" 
    });
  },
  color: 'green',
  textColor: 'white' 
});
```

This way, if a user presses next or previous, or otherwise changes the view or date range being displayed, fullCalendar will automatically call the function defined in "events" with the correct start/end dates and fetch the events into the calendar.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Your suggestion is the the way I originally coded it.  Unfortunately the MySQL call takes about 1.3-1.8 seconds roundtrip and makes it an unpleasant UX experience. 

The stringify was part of my debugging struggle trying to guess at what was happening to my events.  The same applies to moving the ajax call out from eventSources into a seperate call.

Comment: I would suggest fixing your SQL query and/or PHP then. Fetching a small number of events like this shouldn't take too long really, unless you're adding hundreds of events into a single calendar view? You can also help the user experience maybe by adding a "loading...please wait" spinner somewhere in the page while the ajax is running. Users are more likely to be patient if they realise the data is on its way and it hasn't crashed. And...it doesn't look like you have, but make sure the ajax is not running in synchronous mode, because that really does make for horrible UX.

Comment: Agree spinner/overlay already there. But we're loading 30 days ~ 4800 events.  Previous version loaded data page by page with a round-trip in between.  Issue is actually bad architecture but it isn't mine and it is foundational.  This is a transitional version and we have to use the old db schema.  There will be a redesign for the ng2 version when we ditch Codeigniter.

Comment: if you've got that many events then actually I'd say <2 seconds loading time isn't that bad - you have to factor in the time that it takes for fullCalendar to actually process the JSON and render that much HTML as well. I'm surprised it's actually a useful view to have that much data in the 30-day month view though, most of them must be invisible, even on a large screen? Perhaps you should restrict the available views to weeks, or even days? That way more of the events will be visible, and you'll have to load a lot less of them per ajax request.

Comment: You're right on every point.  Too many slots to view effectively on any view other than listDay.  So, i've refactored into two fullCalendars.  Calendar "A" only displays 1 week's events as listDay.  Calendar "B" can be viewed as basicWeek or month with only one event per day if there are any available timeslots.  Clicking the event on Cal "B" positions the user on Cal "A"'s listDay view with detail timeslots.  Its a kluge but its fast and and gives good UX.

Comment: As an asside - I went from loading ~4800 events for 30 days to loading a maximum of 1098 events (1008) for the week and (90) for the next 90 days of events.  Then I reload up to 1008 events on each day event click.  Since the clinics aren't open 24x7 the week actually contains less than 1008 events.  1008 is the practical maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer to this last night.  Apparently my JSON data had been cached.  Clearing my browser cache and rebooting the server fixed my problem (after removing the JSON.stringify that I had put in for testing.